# Is there a function that satisfies $f(\log \frac{p}{1-p}) = p(1-p)$?

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function, functional-equations

> Let $p\in (0,1)$ I am wondering there exists a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,{1\over 2}]$ that satisfies
>   $$
> f\left(\log \frac{p}{1-p}\right) = p(1-p)
> $$

I've tried messing around with exponentials but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $x= \log \frac{p}{1-p}$ then $p = {e^x\over e^x+1}$ so $$f(x) =  {e^x\over e^x+1}\left(1- {e^x\over e^x+1}\right) = {e^x\over (e^x+1)^2}$$

and clearly $f(x)\in [0,{1\over 2}]$.

Comment: Why are you unconventionally assuming that $\log$ is base $10$ instead of base $e$?

Comment: Because in my country it is convenctonaly. Logarithm with base $e$ is denoted by $ln$ from latin *logarithmus naturalis*

Comment: You're on a global platform, though. I'd like to up vote, but your noncompliance with a standard definition prevents me from doing so.

Comment: Ok, I have no problem with that.

Comment: @GitGud: I think it is stretching it quite a bit to call using base-10 logarithms "noncompliance with a standard definition". It is one of the common meanings of the $\log$ symbol, and the difference is more related to which field you're working in than what country you are in.

Comment: @GitGud You are statement is not right. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Particular_bases) In math it is always a matter of definition.

Comment: The ISO's stands on this doesn't comply with the mathematical culture. The standard, among mathematicians, is that $\log$ is base $e$. This shouldn't be new for anyone with a (relatively) large exposure to mathematics. @callculus

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sure, it's one of the common meanings. But among mathematicians it pales in comparison to the use of base $e$.

Comment: For the record, I intended base $e$ logarithm but it makes no difference to me as the analysis is essentially the same. Thanks!

Comment: In pure mathematics, one might even say that the only logarithm (of interest) is the natural one, and the other bases merely differ by an arbitrary scaling factor.  The use of $\ln$ and $\log$ is prevalent as a pedagogical tool for students, in which the latter is introduced first because counting in base $10$ is more familiar, but by the time one has attained an undergraduate level education in mathematics, $\log$ is nearly universally understood as synonymous to $\ln$.